# How do I merge select statement from 2 different tables where I need by_user_id from table 1 for table 2 select statment to get username?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I merge select statement from 2 different tables where I need by_user_id from table 1 for table 2 select statment to get username?

```
SELECT ans, by_user_id, datetime 
FROM answer 
WHERE qn_id = :qn_id
UNION
SELECT username 
FROM user 
WHERE by_user_id = ???
```

Comment: You can't have union with different amount of columns. Seems like you either want a second select statement or join the user name to the first query

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you  mean is just `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.ans, a.by_user_id, a.datetime ,
    u.username
FROM answer a
LEFT JOIN user u
ON a.by_user_id = u.id 
WHERE qn_id = :qn_id
```

Comment: I think the `left join` is overkill, but it should work.

Comment: I agree, if data was inserted properly and there is no deleted user for example and no lost (or empty)  ids in `by_user_id`   we can just `INNER JOIN` but that is my habbit, that helps to debug and to find broken links in data.

Comment: . . You should be careful with that habit.  Outer joins affect the optimization of the query.  If they are not necessary, then an inner join will sometimes have better performance.  Your tactic is fine for ad-hoc queries, but for queries that are part of an application or that will be run multiple times, it is normally best to let the optimizer have as many options as possible.